# Images can be load in Phalcon

Tags: image, .htaccess, phalcon

My images are not loaded with Phalcon Framework.

Maybe because the .htaccess file. I don't know.

The framework return this error:

> **"ImgController handler class cannot be loaded"**, when access http://domain.com/img/tiger.jpg

The route "http://domain.com/projects/update/1" is OK.

My .htaccess files below.

```
#/.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ public/    [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

#/public/.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

What's worng ?

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a routing problem, especially if something works and something isn't. Phalcon digests the uri, finds a route, but cannot dispatch the `ImgController`. Check that the naming is correct, that your have the correctly named controller (`ImgController` not `ImageController`), that it has the correct namespace. If doesn't help, add your routing configuration details and your ImgController and where it is located.

Comment: Ian, in the URL (http://domain.com/img/tiger.jpg) 'img' is the path name that the images are.
The ImgController does exists.

Comment: Do I understood correctly that both the file `/img/tiger.jpg` exist and ImgController exist?

Comment: I just want show a image in the img tag, like this: <img src="http://domain.com/img/tiger.jpg">. The image path is /public/img
But, the framework returns that error: ImgController handler class cannot be loaded.

Comment: Are you running Apache? Did you try using [server configuration](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/apache.html) instead of .htaccess?

Comment: Ian, i was stupid.
i had a error in my images path.
My fault! Sorry.